# How to overwrite an error message for page validation in oracle apex 19.1?

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a page validation for a form in oracle apex. In this validation, I call a third party api to get response in json format(the response is either a success message or an detailed error message). When we got the error message from the api, then page validation is failed. With the customized error message in oracle apex, I don't know how to add the detailed error message from the api. Any ideas on how i can overwrite the error message for oracle apex page validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on your version of APEX, but in 18.2 you have different types of code for the validation. So you can just pick PLSQL code returning error message, and if your outside api returns the message, your plsql code returns the message, if it returns the success message, you return null.

Or you could put in a RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR call with the text from the outside api.

Comment: I solved it by using the apex_error procedure to add the error message!

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using javascript:

```
apex.message.showErrors({
            type:       "error",
            location:   [ "page"],
            message:    "Your message",     
            unsafe:     false
        });
```